# Why are BGP tables suddenly filled with IPv4 routes?

Tags: ipv4, bgp, bgp-ipv6

According to [article](https://blog.apnic.net/2021/03/03/what-will-happen-when-the-routing-table-hits-1024k/) I looked at, bgp routing tables are approaching a maximum size and this is linked to IPv4 exhaustion. Why is this problematic and what is the cause? Will this be a problem with IPv6 and if not, why is that?

Comment: This is not "sudden" because the IPv4 Internet routing tables have been growing for decades. There really is no maximum except what a particular router can handle. The full IPv4 Internet routing table is about a million routes at this point. I remember when it was a quarter of that size, and people were saying it cannot get any larger. The routers were simply replaced with routers that have more resources. The article explains: "_It’s not a simple matter of every network operator running into this problem. The internal tables of network operators can vary according to design._"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are BGP tables suddenly filled with IPv4 routes?

There is nothing sudden about it.  Every entity that receive the full BGP table (both ISPs and large organizations) is well aware of the table size and its steady growth.

The article suggests that there may be routers in use with hardware or software limits on the maximum number of routes they can handle.  Hardware or software upgrades are a regular occurrence for most organizations, so any limit the organizations run into can be dealt with.

There have been many "limits" passed before, and no doubt many to come.